# How to store the result of multiple select queries into one csv file?

Tags: postgresql

How to store the result of all of the queries below into one CSV file in PostgreSQL by executing one COPY (......) to.... statement.

```
select id,name from first;
select id,salary,father_name from second;
select id,score,bonus,extra from third;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

far as i know not possible if you want append one table after another to same file. But you can get them to same file using union

SQL:

```
select f.id as fid , null sid   from first f union select null fid , s.id sid from second s
```

that would create file where all data from first table are
1;null
2;null
....
and second table 
null;1
null;2

or you can use psql command line tool in linux and call :

```
psql mydb -c "select id,name from first; " >> myOutFile.txt
psql mydb -c "select id,salary,father_name from second; " >> myOutFile.txt
psql mydb -c "select id,score,bonus,extra from third; " >> myOutFile.txt
```

In *nix, the > (greater than) character operator redirects output to a file, overwriting the file.

When doubled, the >> operator redirects output to a file appending the redirected output at the end.